# Why does pyqt subthread freezes GUI when doing heavy repetitive work?

Tags: qt, pyqt, qthread, qobject, qtimer

In this simulated example I am repeating a task every 1 second using QTimer by implementing a QObject, then move it to a QThead. The simulated task takes 0.5 second. The task runs in a new thread, which should not have interfered with the main thread in which the GUI is running. However, the task will freeze the GUI repetitively.

```py
import sys
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QThread, pyqtSignal, QObject, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)

class Worker(QObject):
    progress = pyqtSignal(int)
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.i=0
        self.Timer=QTimer(self)
        self.Timer.timeout.connect(self.run)
        self.Timer.setInterval(1000)

    def run(self):
        """Long-running task."""
        sleep(0.5)
        self.i=self.i+1
        self.progress.emit(self.i)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.clicksCount = 0
        self.setupUi()

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Freezing GUI")
        self.resize(300, 150)
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        # Create and connect widgets
        self.clicksLabel = QLabel("Counting: 0 clicks", self)
        self.clicksLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.stepLabel = QLabel("Long-Running Step: 0")
        self.stepLabel.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.countBtn = QPushButton("Click me!", self)
        self.countBtn.clicked.connect(self.countClicks)
        self.longRunningBtn = QPushButton("Long-Running Task!", self)
        self.longRunningBtn.clicked.connect(self.runLongTask)
        # Set the layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.clicksLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.countBtn)
        layout.addStretch()
        layout.addWidget(self.stepLabel)
        layout.addWidget(self.longRunningBtn)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def countClicks(self):
        self.clicksCount += 1
        self.clicksLabel.setText(f"Counting: {self.clicksCount} clicks")

    def reportProgress(self, n):
        self.stepLabel.setText(f"Long-Running Step: {n}")
        
        
    def runLongTask(self):
        # Step 2: Create a QThread object
        self.thread = QThread()
        # Step 3: Create a worker object
        self.worker = Worker()
        # Step 4: Move worker to the thread
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        # Step 5: Connect signals and slots
        
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.Timer.start)

        self.thread.finished.connect(self.thread.deleteLater)
        self.worker.progress.connect(self.reportProgress)
        # Step 6: Start the thread
        self.thread.start()


        self.longRunningBtn.setEnabled(False)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = Window()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

If I reduce the work in the task by removing `sleep()` or setting a smaller time for the `sleep()` function in `Worker.run()`, then the GUI will not freeze. However, realistically I am doing a task that requires a long time to complete, which makes it a problem.

Comment: You're not running the task in the other thread. When `Timer` is created, it still belongs to the main thread, and so the connected function will still run in the main thread. Try to add `self.worker.Timer.moveToThread(self.thread)` before connecting its `start` slot.

Comment: Hi @musicamante: Thanks for the reply. I added that before connecting `start`, but the problem persists. I do not agree that the task is not in the other thread, because in that case removing the `sleep()` in run should not have made the GUI freeze disappear.  In fact, even if I set the Interval of `Timer` to 0 (similar to infinite loop), as long as I do not put `sleep()` in `Worker.run()`, the GUI will NOT freeze.

Comment: QTimer is not blocking, `sleep` is, and you *are* running that in the main thread. Just add `print(int(QThread.currentThreadId()))` when you create the QApplication, and add another one within `def run(self):` of the worker and you'll see that they are the same. If `run` was actually running in a separate thread, those numbers will not be the same.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the ideas and inputs from the comments. It turns out that the problem comes from the fact that `run` is a member function of the `Worker` class, but is not a Signal or Slot of the `Worker` class. Moving the worker to the new thread only affect its Signals and Slots, not `run`. So `run` is still executed in the main thread.

One solution will be to use the `@pyqtSlot()` decorator when defining `run`, to make it a `Slot` of the Worker class. Also, specifying `DirectionConnection` between `Timer.timeout` and `Worker.run` can also force the `run` function to run in the newly created thread that `Timer` has been moved to.

Comment: No, that's not the reason. And, even though adding the slot decorator is a possible solution, the problem is not that "it is not a signal or slot" (which, by the way, are completely different things), but mainly because you created the QTimer in the main thread. While this is not an error per se, it could lead to problems if you're not careful (or you don't understand how threading works). When a connection to a *function* (not a slot) is done, it will base the thread affinity on the thread in which it was created, and that's why, as I pointed out, `run()` was executed in the main thread.

Comment: Considering this, an alternative to the above could be to just create QTimer within the `run()` function, and connect it to a *separate* function that actually does what `run()` right now does. Unrelated notes: 1. only classes or constants should have capitalized names, not variables or attributes (`self.timer`, not `self.Timer`); 2. use *spaces* around operators: readability is a fundamental aspect in programming, and it's even more important when sharing code with others (like posting on StackOverflow); see the official [Style Guide for Python Code](//python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008).

Comment: Thanks @musicamante for these informative inputs. Very detailed and educative. I did some more learning myself and find some different explanations and solutions that might be also useful: 1) I set the parent of `self.timer` as the worker, so it is fine to just move the worker to the thread, since the children of QObject are automatically moved to the new thread. 2) the problem of my code is that signal connections should be done after moving the QObjects, including the timer, to the target thread.